# Отправка POST запроса при помощи Curl

Tags: php

```
$curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, '......');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '.......');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Opera 10.00');
            $res = curl_exec($curl);
                echo $res;
            curl_close($curl);
```

Так я отправляю post запрос. Ответ записывается в переменную $res и отображается на странице. Проблема в том, что в $res находится только часть ответа, а именно Headers( например

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server  nginx/1.2.7
Date    Wed, 29 May 2013 18:12:15 GMT
Content-Type    text/xml; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Connection  keep-alive
```

), но в ответе еще есть текст с ответом от сервера (отслеживал запросы через Charles). Как мне его получить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтоб убедиться в том, что кроме заголовков (*кстати, зачем он вам?*) точно еще что-то приходит, попробуйте записать результат в файл:

```
// ...
$res = curl_exec($curl);
file_put_contents("test.txt",$res);
curl_close($curl);
// ...
```

Если ссодержимое страницы присутствует, то остается вытащить его необходимую часть. Для этого можно воспользоваться удобным для вас инструментом: или [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart), или [phpQuery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/), или каким-то другим парсером.

Кроме того, возможно, что надо декодировать запрос. Для этого добавьте:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip, deflate");
```